# Simple Indesign cc script (I hope)

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, script

I keep having to do the same ting over and over.  I get a text file with a 2-line header and the there is one list of names.  I need to keep the header full width of the page and then have the two groups in two columns.  The two groups don't always have the same number of people, but they are labels "Group 1" and "Group 2"  Currently I just have a previously used group of three frames and I just drag the two single column frames to the appropriate height, but there are so many of these it would be great to have something automated.  Like select the entire text block, make 3 frames all the same length, etc.  Any ideas?  I do vba and actions in PhotoShop all the time, but scripts elude me.

Comment: A image would supplement your explanationa and would go a long way forward describing what your after. I dont see why you would need a script for your explanation that table wouldn't do

Comment: If you don't know how to do it yourself, be careful with qualifying writing a script as "simple"  That said, I agree with @jooja: I'm having troubles following your description, so an image or two (before/after) would be useful. Pending that, writing up something might or might not be simple for me - I can't say yet.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may be doing some sort of text merge. The heading style can be set to "span" columns. That way you would need only one (two column) frame.